# How to add Source editing plugin to CKEditor v5 when loaded from CDN?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ckeditor5

I want to use CKEditor v5 and load it from CDN. I also want to use [Source editing](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/source-editing.html) plugin

I wonder if I can use

1. https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing
2. [CKEditor 5 DLL builds](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/alternative-setups/dll-builds.html)

For 1. I tried to create [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/pd8Luh2c/7/). BUt it does not work.

```
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core@39.0.0/src/index.min.js "></script>
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing@39.0.0/src/index.min.js "></script>
// llink href=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing@36.0.1/theme/sourceediting.min.css " rel="stylesheet">

<div id="editor">text</div>

<script>
  ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#text-editor'), {
      plugins: [SourceEditing, /* ... */ ],
      toolbar: ['sourceEditing', /* ... */ ]
    })
    .then(editor => {
      console.log(editor);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });

</script>
```

For 2. the documentation says `In order to run the editor, you need to load the necessary files (base DLL + editor creator + features). These files expose their content in the CKEditor5 global, using the following format:` But I cannot find anywhere the correct path to Source editing plugin so I can use it as dll

Could you help me to set it so Source editing plugin can be loaded fro CDN?

Comment: This site informs about DLL builds: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/alternative-setups/dll-builds.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use dll as following:

```
Script: https://unpkg.com/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing@39.0.2/build/source-editing.js
plugins: CKEditor5.sourceEditing.SourceEditing
toolbars: sourceEditing
```

I made a demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/haison8x/5g9b0t1a/